# Profile image goes over the text on advance forum in drupal 7

Tags: media, theming, nodes

I'm fairly new to Drupal and I'm testing out [Advanced Forum](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module on my site.

The problem I'm facing is that when photo which is uploaded is bigger than user info layout, then it goes over the text. Is there any way to force image to stretch and fit into the user info block?

I tried changing css, but I'm not really sure which one to change and in what manner. I'm using silver bells...

Can anyone guide me through this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's your first problem...instead of silver bells, try using the keyboard :P In all seriousness though, what are silver bells in this context?

Comment: I guess it's an [advanced forum style](http://drupal.org/node/1004738).

Answer (score 0):

It might not be exactly the answer you're looking for, but using CSS only, you can add this rule to your theme's main css file:

```
img{
max-width: 100%;
}
```